# Make new column based on only the first value of another column while fill others with 0

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a data frame and a key, `key[1,2,3,4]` :

```
Animal Arm 
1      2
1      4
1      3
1      3
1      1
1      1
```

I want to create a new column called `response` based on the condition that if the arm values are in the key then response is equal to `1` else response is equal to `0`. However the trick is that it should be only for the first values only and any repetition of the arm value should yield a `response` as `0`. Just like this :

```
Animal  Arm  Response
1       2    1  
1       4    1
1       3    1
1       3    0
1       1    1
1       1    0
```

There can be only a maximum of 4 value having `response` as `1`

This is what i tried :

```
resp = []    
for i in range(len(df3)):
            for j in key:
                if df['Arm'][i] == j:
                    resp.append(1)
                    break
            else: resp.append(0)


df['Response'] = resp
```

but i dont know how to make only the first values of the key as 1 and any repition of the values as zero.

Can someone help?

Comment: Do you need check duplicates per `Animal` and `Arm` ? Or only per `Arm` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) with [`DataFrame.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) - per both columns for test duplicated values per `Animal` and `Arm`, in another words duplicated values of `Arm` are tested per groups by `Animal`

*I understand this logic from tag `group-by`.*

```
df['Response'] = (df['Arm'].isin(key) & ~df.duplicated(['Animal','Arm'])).astype(int)
print (df)
   Animal  Arm  Response
0       1    2         1
1       1    4         1
2       1    3         1
3       1    3         0
4       1    1         1
5       1    1         0
```

Add data for see difference:

```
key = [1,2,3,4]
df['Response'] = (df['Arm'].isin(key) & ~df.duplicated(['Animal','Arm'])).astype(int)
print (df)
    Animal  Arm  Response
0        1    2         1
1        1    4         1
2        1    3         1
3        1    3         0
4        1    1         1
5        1    1         0
6        2    2         1
7        2    4         1
8        2    3         1
9        2    3         0
10       2    1         1
11       2    1         0
```

Comment: you just changed your answer to be identical to mine :(

Comment: @mozway - check again.

Comment: it's virtually the same, Animal is not described to have any role

Comment: in this case the nice thing to do it to comment on the answer, not replace yours… anyway, not like if this was the first time… your original answer was completely different

Comment: @mozway - Not understand your problem, added answer, added condition, answer is different like your, so what is problem,? If I ask you with same problem, it is perfectly OK, but now is something wrong?

Comment: The issue was that originally your had a [completely different logic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vecwk.png), but anyway, I'm just tired… do this if you want, you have your moral/ethic, if you don't see the issue, then nothing I'll say will change anything.

Comment: @mozway - Sorry, if I have same problem with you (it was perfectly fine by your comemnts), so what is problem now? Found problem in my answer, is few seconds correct, what is your morale/ethic problem?

Comment: @mozway - Also if was create different answers what is problem? If OP need not per both columns use your answer,.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) combined with [`duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html):

```
df['Response'] = (df['Arm'].isin(key)&~df['Arm'].duplicated()).astype(int)
```

Or:

```
df['Response'] = np.where(df['Arm'].isin(key)&~df['Arm'].duplicated(), 1, 0)
```

Output:

```
   Animal  Arm  Response
0       1    2         1
1       1    4         1
2       1    3         1
3       1    3         0
4       1    1         1
5       1    1         0
```

Comment: @Kshtj which other values? Can you explicit your issue with an example?

Answer (score 0):

```
resp = [] 
respDone= []
for i in range(len(df)):
    for j in key:
        if df['Arm'][i] == j and df["Arm"][i] not in respDone:
            resp.append(1)
            respDone.append(df["Arm"][i])
            break
    else: resp.append(0)


df['Response'] = resp
```